# Unable to set UIView background color from Controller

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uiview, xcode4.6

I have an app (XCode 4.6, Storyboards, iOS 6.2 and ARC) with several UIViews:

[image]

Each of the UIViews has the background color defined in XCode.  I want to be able to change the background color (currently lightYellow) based on user selected schemes.  In the CalendarViewController's **-viewDidLoad** method, I have this code:

```
self.leftGrid.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.leftGrid setNeedsDisplay];
```

This is the code in the CalendarViewController's .h file:

```
//  these all all UIViews
@class SubViewGrid;
@class SubViewData;
@class CalendarView;
@class TopGrid;
@class LeftGrid;

@interface CalendarViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>  {

}

//  UIScrollView properties
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIScrollView *schedScrollView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *topGrid;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *leftGrid;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *topGridSV;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *leftGridSV;
```

The problem is: nothing happens!  What am I doing wrong?  (I have looked at SO and Googled, but found nothing pertinent)

Comment: Is leftGrid marked as IBOutlet, and connected to your class in IB ?

Comment: Is it happens when view is loaded? F.e in viewDidLoad:? Not in init method

Comment: I edited the question... I added the @class lines to remove errors I was getting quite awhile ago, but not sure what they do other than prevent circular references...

Comment: Did you check self.leftGrid for nil in viewDidLoad ? Maybe owner of xib seted incorrect? Or connection between view in IB and it's owner field?

Comment: Please re-write your comment as an answer... that wasn't exactly it, but there was a check to see if a flag was set indicating which color scheme was requested, and *that* was nil.  Thank you for your help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `self.leftGrid == nil` in `viewDidLoad`. Maybe owner of xib setted incorrect. Or connection between view in IB and it's owner field.